# It is possible to receive an alert when we have an action planified?

Tags: extension, civicase

I would like to receive a notification when I plan a future action in Civicase ? For exemple, if I plan to call a prospect next monday, is it possible to have at 9 am an alert on the following monday telling me that I have to do this specific call ? It is possible ? It is possible to receive the alterts on Slack or Google Agenda ?
Should I had an extension ?
Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried scheduled reminders? It can be based on activities. See https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/email/scheduled-reminders/

Answer (score 1):

Another option for sending reminders where Scheduled Reminders do not apply is via CiviRules